# Insert Arrays into Combobox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, split

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim window As New System.IO.StreamReader("Pfad", True)
    Dim lines As String
    Dim Element As String()
    Dim SplitArray As String()
    lines = window.ReadToEnd
    Element = lines.Split("!")
    Element.Count


    For i = 0 To Element.Count - 1
        SplitArray = Element(i).Split(Chr(13))
    Next

    ComboBox1.Items.Add(SplitArray)

End Sub
```

Hello I'm a Newbie. I want to fill my Combobox with the results of the split.

Answer (score 2):

Use addrange to fill combobox items with array of strings

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(SplitArray)
```

Comment: That worked. You also know how I can insert the selection that I find in the combo box in the text fields? I have a front end for it.

Comment: do you want show the selection text on a textbox field?

Comment: try "textfield.text =  ComboBox1.text "